# How can I add html template to the checkout onepage?

Tags: magento2, javascript, html

Checkout generate from `onepage.phtml` file that generate another html page inside like `details.html` for `billing-address` and another html file. How can I add new html file to generate inside the `onepage.phtml`?

Answer (score 0):

For this , you have to override the checkout module and in your layout file `checkout_index_index.xml` add a child block inside the

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\AbstractCart" name="onepage.checkout.details" as="onepage_checkout" template="Magento_Checkout::onepage.phtml" cacheable="false"> <block class="YourNameSpace\YourModule\Block\YourCustomBlock" name="any-unique-name" as="anyuniquestring" template="YourNamespace_YourModule::yourcustomtemplate.phtml" /></block>
```

Make sure you create your custom block and template file in your module. Run the setup upgrade and refresh.

Comment: And where should i place my customtemplate.phtml file?

Comment: In your module's template folder

Comment: Should it in `view/frontend/templates`?

Comment: It should be under  NameSpace_Module/templates  folder.
For example, if you are overriding checkout module, then your required template file should be in   app/design/frontend/YourNameSpace/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout/templates/your-custom-template.phtml